# Posting nested collection from MVC view to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of `Line` that contains a list of `RowLane`, for every line it has a list of `RowLane`.

That's the result:

[image]

The view

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("Nome do Grupo")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("Linhas")
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Forms", "ProcessLane", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GroupName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @{
                    foreach (var t in item.RowLane)
                    {
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => t.IsChecked)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => t.LaneName)                           
                    }
                }
            </td>
            <td>               
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Adicionar" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>                
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
}
```

And classes :

```
public class Line
{
    public int IdGroup { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public List<RowLane> RowLane { get; set; }
}

public class RowLane
{
    public string IdLane { get; set; }
    public string LaneName { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

I need to collect only the GroupID and all the checked box from the row selected.

Comment: You can use editor templates to solve this, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48452115/multi-select-checkboxlist-in-asp-net-mvc-5/48452379#48452379). Also what is the point of multiple submit buttons when your form is outside the loop ? Clicking on any button for any row will submit all data.

Comment: For each group I can assign one or more Lanes for this group.

Comment: could you rearrange the view ?

Comment: What you mean ?

Comment: Imagine like this is a ListView and each row has a `onClick` method, what I want do is, if I click on the Button for this row, I get all the checked items value.

Comment: You want it on client side ? then use javascript to listen to the click event and read the items from DOM.

Comment: Don't want to use Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, **to post the data of selected line from view to controller**, you can simply have:

```
@model List<Path.To.Your.Models.Line>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "test";
}

<h2>test</h2>



@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{    
  <form action=@Url.Action("ProcessLane", new { IdGroup = Model[i].IdGroup}) method="post">        
    <div class="row parentWrap">
        @for (var j = 0; j < Model[i].RowLane.Count; j++)
        {
           <div class="row">
               @Html.Hidden("[" + j + "].IdLane", Model[i].RowLane[j].IdLane)
               @Html.Hidden("[" + j + "].LaneName", Model[i].RowLane[j].LaneName)
               @Html.CheckBox("[" + j + "].IsChecked")
               @Html.Label(Model[i].RowLane[j].LaneName)
           </div>
        }
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary sss" value="send" />
    </div>
  </form>
  <hr />    
}
```

and, some sample data to check in your Controller:

```
public ActionResult test()
    {
        IEnumerable<Line> line = new List<Line> 
            { new Line{
                 IdGroup = 100,
                 GroupName = "Nojan",
                 RowLane = new List<RowLane> { new RowLane { IdLane = "1", IsChecked = true, LaneName = "pizza"},
                                               new RowLane { IdLane = "2", IsChecked = false, LaneName = "lazogna"}
                 }
                },
                 new Line{
                 IdGroup = 101,
                 GroupName = "Noj",
                 RowLane = new List<RowLane> { new RowLane { IdLane = "3", IsChecked = false, LaneName = "pizza"},
                                               new RowLane { IdLane = "4", IsChecked = false, LaneName = "lazogna"}
                 }
            }                     
    };

        return View(line.ToList());
    }


public ActionResult ProcessLane(int? IdGroup, List<RowLane> input)
{
        // Code here as you wish, form is submitted to this method
}
```

I ran and tested the code successfully. You may customize it as you please.

Hope this helped :)